# Software to check source of freezing crashes

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, power-supply, freeze, crash

My computer keeps crashing regularly. Basically everyday. It never did that and only started when I got back home after being away for more than a week.

It starts by jittering and slowing down a lot. Any video playing will start loading then stop completely.
The mouse gets slower and ends up not moving anymore.

Whether I try as it happens or once everything is totally frozen, I can’t go into start menu or ctrl alt del to restart.

Everytime I have to shutdown the laptop.

Is there a software that helps diagnose what’s going on? I remember there is one that’s free and everyone recommends, where you can export a report.
Is there a software that can tell me if my power supply or hard drives or ram is failing ?

Today it ran all afternoon with no issues while it downloaded a game. But tonight after 1/2h of watching some live twitch while working on excel, it just did it again.

It’s a 3-y gaming laptop running Windows 10.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: With modern computers (multi-core) "freezing" where the mouse doesn't even move is often a hardware issue. It could be overheating, corrupt RAM, failing power supply, or the C: drive that Windows runs on could be dying. Diagnosing those kinds of issues is hard to do with software alone. You usually need to check one component at a time in isolation from the rest to narrow it down. If it is a software issue, there would almost always be an error logged in the windows Event Viewer to look for.

Comment: But it ran fast even if it was really hot weather and then I went away and right from the first boot it started doing that

Comment: Any software that supports reading the S.M.A.R.T data from the HDD firmware can determine what the drive is reporting.  Only power supplies that support software reporting would have software to determine their health.  Unless you have hardware running the measures the power draw of the power supply, you will be hard pressed, to find any software that provide accurate reporting.  Obviously if your machine if freezing any software running will also freeze.

Comment: I trying running the Lenovo diagnostics tools on their site. I dunno how reliable they are. The computer froze / crashed several times. However one time I did these without my external monitor plugged in (through DisplayPort) and then it ran fine for many hours and crashed shortly after plugging the screen. Could it be the cable or something ?

Comment: What should I look for in Events Viewer? Seems like there are errors in there but also many are not too catastrophic and dealt with by the OS.